# Concat specified js files and copy all the other js files to output dir

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I want to concat a couple of js files I have in my `src/` directory, like the ones that are needed on every page and for some specific pages that need multiple files. 
The rest of the files I want to copy with the current directory structure in tact. These are the files that are used only on one page and are the only page specific jsfile for that page.

So I would like to exclude the `src` and `files` attributes of the first type of tasks and exclude those in the last task.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you use compression, minification then probably it is more efficient to glue everything into a big file. The downloaded file size won't be much bigger and you spare a few requests at least. If you have client side caching as well then this additional few percent of network usage would be one time only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use create an array with all the files you mean to concatenate outside task scope. Then you loop through that array to concatenate the `javascript` files listed in the array in one task like `uglify` and create another task to copy all the files through another task like `copy`.

But the magic would happen when you use the same pre-defined array to list the exceptions that are *not* going to be included in the `copy` task.

*OR* you could prefixes like:

```
uglify: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'dest/output.min.js': [
                'app/js/**/concatenate-*.js',
            ]
        }
    }
}

copy: {
    dist: {
        src : [
            'app/js/**/*.js',
            // exclude files
            '!app/js/**/concatenate-*.js'
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that I only added the relevant part within each task, normally the tasks would need more configuration than just that.